# Jenkins Error Log in GrayLog2

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, graylog2

We are noticing that any errors that occur in our Jenkins service go unattended until it is too late and we were looking for a way to get our Jenkins error log on our server into GrayLog2. Are there any plugins or scripts that will handle this for us?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is for Graylog2, but we have been using HipCHat to get real time updates from Jenkins about builds etc. (we also use it to get GIT activity on projects from Stash).

I would highly recommend it as an alternative if you do not win with GrayLog2.